# How to create instance specific function counter?

Tags: python, class, counter, instance-variables

I would like to track function count inside the class but such that this count is different for each instance of the class.

We can set up a counter on a simple function:

```
def foo1():
    pass

foo1.count = 0
foo1.count +=1
print(foo1.count)
```

Now let`s turn to class methods:

```
class A:
    def foo2(self):
        print('Hi')
```

we can set counter here as well

```
A.foo2.count = 0
a = A()
b = A()
```

but this count is NOT instance specific

```
A.foo2.count += 1
print(a.foo2.count)
print(b.foo2.count)
```

it is not possible to set count for an INSTANCE method:

```
a.foo2.count += 1
```

and if we use `__func__`  it will be equivalent to changing `A.foo2.count`:

```
a.foo2.__func__.count += 1
print(b.foo2.count)
print(a.foo2.count)
print(A.foo2.count)
```

**Question:** how to make `foo2.count` INSTANCE specific ? So that `a` and `b` could have multiple values of `foo2.count` ?

Please note: I am asking about **function** attribute, not class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this then?

```
from collections import defaultdict


def foo1():
    print('Hi')
foo1.count = defaultdict(int)

class A:

    def foo2(self):
        foo1()
        foo1.count[self] += 1



a = A()
b = A()

a.foo2()
a.foo2()
b.foo2()

print(foo1.count)
```

output:

```
Hi
Hi
Hi
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {<__main__.A object at 0x000001E59759ABE0>: 2, <__main__.A object at 0x000001E596AFCD30>: 1})
```

Comment: Like your idea but what will happen if instance of the class is heavy ? Say you created 1mln instances, then this dictionary could be big ? Or this doesn`t matter because size(hash(self)) << size(self) ?

Answer (score 1):

use the `__init__` method:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count_foo2 = 0

    def foo2(self):
        print('Hi')
        self.count_foo2 += 1 


a = A()
b = A()

a.foo2()

print(a.count_foo2)
print(b.count_foo2)
```

Output:

```
Hi
1
0
```

Comment: count_foo2 is an attribute of the class instance, not the function. I was asking about the function attribute.

Comment: you have to decide whether count is an attribute of the function or the class instance...   By all mean your usage seems to indicate it should be an instance attribute. Why don't you tell us about the real problem you are trying to solve, this sounds like an XY issue...

Comment: I would like to create a "counter" class decorator that tracks how many times a function was executed but only "within" this specific class instance. I was hoping to avoid creating instance attributes (like in your example) and work with functions directly

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. I am not sure this is entirely what you want as in one of your comments you indicated that you wanted specifically function instance attributes (?). This however seems to *behave* the way you described. It has the benefit of working regardless of how many methods for which you want this behavior to occur.

```
def fn_exec_count(base_fn):
    def new_fn(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fn_count_attr = 'fn_' + base_fn.__name__ + '_count'
        if not hasattr(self, fn_count_attr):
            setattr(self, fn_count_attr, 1)
        else:
            setattr(self, fn_count_attr, getattr(self, fn_count_attr) + 1)
        base_fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    new_fn.__name__ = base_fn.__name__
    return new_fn

class A:
    @fn_exec_count
    def foo(self):
        fn_count_attr = 'fn_' + A.foo.__name__ + '_count' 
        print(f'Value of counter: {getattr(self, fn_count_attr, None)}')


a1 = A()
a1.foo()
a1.foo()
a2 = A()
a2.foo()
a1.foo()
```

Outputs:

```
Value of counter: 1
Value of counter: 2
Value of counter: 1
Value of counter: 3
```

Edit: Stealing from Julien's answer to use defaultdict makes this slightly less verbose.

```
def fn_exec_count_dict(base_fn):
    def new_fn(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, 'fn_exec_count'):
            setattr(self, 'fn_exec_count', defaultdict(int))
        self.fn_exec_count[base_fn.__name__] += 1
        base_fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    new_fn.__name__ = base_fn.__name__
    return new_fn

class A:
    @fn_exec_count_dict
    def foo(self):
        print(f'Value of counter: {self.fn_exec_count[A.foo.__name__]}')

# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to accept Julien`s because he was the first one to to come up with a way to create a function, not class attribute, but I appreciate your help and effor !